# Getting error: "missing $ inserted", "missing { inserted" ; all errors output.bbl lines that don't make sense to me

Tags: errors, missing

I've noticed that a lot of ppl have problem with the mentioned error messages and it seems as if they're caused by all kinds of small-ish syntax errors, which don't necessarily have anything to do with math equations.

I admittedly sped through the basics of overleaf-tutorials and other sources that I found through google ofc and pieced an overleaf document together that throws all kind of errors, but errors the compiler seems to be able to handle - even if it adds $-symbols (according to the error messages), where none are needed...?

I'm writing an homework assignment with **Overleaf**:
- article
- natbib
- bibliographystyle abbrvnat

So far my code seems pretty clean to me, which is why I'm wondering where the compiler is possible misinterpreting so much.

My code so far goes as follows. I hope the German language doesnt cause any trouble, as all keywords and syntax-structures are English ofc.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage[margin=22mm]{geometry}% <-------- CHANGE HERE for the global margins
%\usepackage{lmodern} % Lädt die Schriftart Latin Modern, die universell skalierbar ist


\setcitestyle{authoryear, open={(},close={)}, colon}
%\setcitestyle{notesep={:}}




\title{Facebook's Rolle im Genozid an den Rohingya}
\author{Joschka Eickhoff}
\date{August 2019}


\renewcommand\contentsname{Literaturverzeichnis}



\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage


%##########################
%#####  EINLEITUNG  #######
%##########################

\section{Einleitung}
Ein grober Abriss über alles was hier behandelt wird.Ein grober Abriss über alles was hier behandelt wird.Ein grober Abriss über alles was hier behandelt wird.Ein grober Abriss über alles was hier behandelt wird.Ein grober Abriss über alles was hier behandelt wird.Ein grober Abriss über alles was hier behandelt wird.Ein grober Abriss über alles was hier behandelt wird.Ein grober Abriss über alles was hier behandelt wird.Ein grober Abriss über alles was hier behandelt wird.Ein grober Abriss über alles was hier behandelt wird.Ein grober Abriss über alles was hier behandelt wird.Ein grober Abriss über alles was hier behandelt wird.Ein grober Abriss über alles was hier behandelt 


%##########################
%#####  Hauptteil  ########
%##########################
\section{Fakenews - früher und heute}
Lange vor der Erfindung des Zeitungsdrucks versuchen Menschen, durch die Verbreitung von Falschnachrichten, andere zu lenken und in ihren Überzeugungen zu manipulieren.\newline
Nachdem Kaiser Justinian um 500 n.Chr. stirbt, versucht sich der Geschichtsschreiber Procopius von Cäsarea vom Kaiser zu distanzieren und verfasst eine verleumderische Schrift "Secret History", um ihn und seine Frau in Verruf zu bringen. Er veröffentlicht die Schrift nach dem Tod, weil er dann, dank verstorbener Zeugen, keine Vergeltung zu befürchten hat.\newline
In der Ära des Zeitungsdrucks kommt in Frankreich um das 17. Jahrhundert ein Bericht in Umlauf, der behauptet, eine in Chile gefangene Drachen-ähnliche Kreatur würde nach Frankreich transportiert werden. Teil des Berichts ist eine Gravur der Kreatur. Während der französischen Revolution wird der Kreatur das Gesicht von Marie Antoinette aufgesetzt, um ihrem Ruf zu schaden.\newline
Der amerikanische Schriftsteller Edgar Allan Poe verfasste 1844 falsche Nachrichten, als er behauptete, dass ein Ballonfahrer den Atlantik innerhalb von drei Tagen überquert hätte. Durch sein detailliertes und wissenschaftlich fundiertes Vorgehen, schenken viele Menschen der Geschichte ihren Glauben. Weder Ballonfahrer noch Ballon werden jemals gefunden und die Lüge wird aufgedeckt~\citep{alaTechSource}.\newline
Zur der Ära der Massenmedien und der Existenz von Radioübertragung, wird 1938 das Science-Fiction Buch "War of the Worlds" im Radio präsentiert, das von einer Mars-Invasion auf der Erde handelt. Geschrieben war das Buches im Jahr 1889 und Menschen die den Plot der Geschichte zur Zeit der Radiosendung nicht einordnen konnten, sorgten bei Ausstrahlung für eine kleine Panik~\citep{warOfTheWorlds}.\newline
Die mittlerweile geschlossene Website "MartinLutherKing.org" wird als wahrheitsgetreue und den Tatsachen entsprechende Wissensplattform für sowohl Schüler aus auch Lehrpersonal beworben. Betrieben wurde die Website von einer rechtsextremen Gruppe, zur gezielten Diffamierung seiner Person~\citep{MartinLutherKing}.\newline
\newline
Während bei früheren analogen Radioübertragungen davon ausgegangen werden konnte, dass hinter der Ausstrahlung keine Privatperson steckt, unterliegt die Erstellung von Inhalten im Internet weit weniger Beschränkungen. Insbesondere durch moderne Kanäle wie Social Media ist das Erstellen und Verbreiten von Informationen so einfach wie nie zuvor.\newline

\section{Die Protagonisten}
\subsection{Wer sind die Rohingya}
\subsection{Konsquenzen der Rongingya-krise}

\section{Facebook's Rolle}

\section{Wer ist verantwortlich?}

\section{Was muss sich ändern?}


\newpage
\renewcommand\refname{Literaturverzeichnis}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{quellen.bib}

\end{document}
```

**This is my .bib file:**

```
@online{alaTechSource,
  title={History of Fake News},
  author={Burkhardt, Joanna M},
  year={2017},
  howpublished={https://journals.ala.org/index.php/ltr/article/view/6497/8636}
}

@online{warOfTheWorlds,
    title={"The original ‘fake news’? ‘War of the Worlds’ at 80"},
    author={USATODAY},
    year={2018},
    howpublished={https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USpPphVGFSU},
}

@online{MartinLutherKing,
    author = {HuffingtonPost},
    title = {"White Supremacist Site MartinLutherKing.org Marks 12th Anniversary"},
    year = {2011},
    howpublished={https://www.huffpost.com/entry/white-supremacist-site-ma_b_809755}
}
```

**I got the following error messages:**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

These red errors were caused by links which I used in my .bib file. Said links included underscores as in `_`, which I changed to `\_` as suggested.

**Now the only errors that are left are the following:**

[image]

I'm having a lot of `\newline` breaks, so I'm assuming that's were those "underfull \hbox"-errors come from.
I've tried:

- `\newline`
- `\\`
- `\hfill \break`

but nothing solves those "underfull" errors.

I also still wondering what the following error means:

```
BibTeX entry type for "alaTechSource" isn't style-file defined quellen.bib.bib, line 1
```

Comment: Welcome! Possibly you are adding references with urls that contain `_` symbol .... Add these urls inside `_` and if still needed use `\_` instead.

Comment: Hi Josh, Overleaf is not really relevant here: the same errors would generally appear on any TeX installation. But as the errors are reported in the .bbl file (the output of BibTeX, which is used to print the reference list into the document), we need to be able to see your .bib file to see where the errors are coming from.

Comment: also if you want help with an error message show the exact error from the log file, in a code section to preserve line endings

Comment: Thx @koleygr. Your correction made a huge difference.

I also corrected my post, added the bib file, uploaded screenshots of errors and updated, which corrections I made.

Comment: Off topic -- You are not using "balanced" quote marks.  All the quote marks will be printed as "close quotes".  Left-hand quotes should be entered as backticks (doubling them for a double open quote), and the right hand quotes as apostrophes.  The "ditto" character will usually result in a double close quote, but don't count on it; safer to use two singles (apostrophes).

Comment: Welcome @Josh ... Now you have just some warnings

Comment: ! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> $
l.19 $$\parallel Tf(x)\parallel_$${K^{.\alpha,P),\theta}_{q(.)}(w)}$$=
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.